# How to check if fragment was created for the first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sharedpreferences

I would like to check if a fragment was created for the first time so that I can launch a different fragment for introduction before coming to the retained fragment.

Normally for an activity I know I would use a sharedPreference-object to store a boolean value that tells me if this is the first time the user opens the activity, check the preference when the user starts the application, and if it returns true then show the middle screen.
Is the same possible for fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use sharedPrference, but maybe it will be better to check the state when you actually switch to this fragment. 
I mean you can decide in activity if to show introduction fragment or regular one before you create the fragment.